# atm bank program using wxpython , issue i am having is in the first panel when ask for the id # how do i make it accept the correct id

Tags: wxpython

[atm using wxpython](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6VeB.jpg)

this is my code for the customer id but how i get that function to run when click on the OK button in the first panel . using wxpython

```
def main():
    flag = 0
    for i in range(0,3):
        customer_id = input("Enter the Customer ID: ")
        if(isValid(customer_id)):
            flag = 1
            break
        else:
            if(i==2):
                break
        print("That's not a valid ID! You have", 2-i, "more chances!")
    if(flag==1):
        welcomePanel(customer_id)
    else:
        print("You entered the Customer ID incorrectly 3 times!!!")
        print("Exiting the program!")

def isValid(customer_id):
    return True
```

another issue is if the customer enters a valid CustomerID,  in  the welcomePanel() how i make it switch over to another panel where  the user can choose which transaction do they want to make, like opening a savings account, depositing or withdrawing money, checking balance, etc? refer to the picture

Comment: No sign of `wxpython` anywhere in the posted code!

Comment: could send my codes to you